# Netty: Immediately send a message and expect for a response when the clients become connected

Tags: netty

This is my first time of using Netty, and I manage to make my Server and Client works together.

Now I want to add security on it, where the Server is waiting for incoming clients 
and after accepting, the Server will send a Message and Expect for the response within a seconds.
Then, if the Client didn't response, it will be automatically disconnected by the Server. how to do it?

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); // (1)
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

try {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); // (2)
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { // (4)

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());
    }
    }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          // (5)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (6)

    // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
    Log.w(TAG,"SERVER started, waiting for incoming clients...");
    ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); // (7)

    //Immediately send message to the client, but this failed
    Channel channel = f.awaitUninterruptibly().channel();
    channel.writeAndFlush("passsword?\n");
    /** Expect response from client here... but how???  **/


    f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG,"SERVER Exception, >> " + e.toString());
}finally {
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    Log.w(TAG,"SERVER finally Stopped.");
}
```

I even tried to send a message using `channel.writeAndFlush("passsword?\n");` after accepting clients but the client didn't receive anything.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got something wrong the channel a bind operation returns isn't a client channel it's your server channel which manages client channels (Accepting new connections and so on).

If you want to send a packet after a client connection you need to send it in the [channelActive](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html#channelActive-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-) method in one of your client handlers. (In your example it's the ServerHandler)

For more information about netty's state system I have prepared this image:[image: Netty.io state model]

Here an example:

```
public class FooHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Bar> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("HELLO:PASSWORD");
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Bar bar) throws Exception {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Hope that helped

Comment: Seems like I don't have any choice but to handle everything in Handler. What I actually want is create an authentication between Server and Client, let say: `The Server is starting to accept incoming clients`, when there's a new client, let it connect for a moment and before everything else happen I want it first to ask for something like password within 5sec., and if it has a wrong response or the timeout has come, then disconnect the client. But it's OK now, I already used my plan B. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Seems like I don't have any choice but to handle everything in Handler. 
What I actually want is create an authentication between Server and Client, let say: `The Server is starting to accept incoming clients`, when there's a new client, let it connect for a moment and before everything else happen I want it first to ask for something like password within 5sec., and if it has a wrong response or the timeout has come, then disconnect the client otherwise register the client to handler.

Comment: `channelRead0` is for receiving data from any client that is connected to the Server, 
you can't tell if the client is authenticated or not, the connected client is allowed to 
send any message and the server will continue receiving, that's what I think.
But it's OK now, I already used my plan B. Thanks you!

Comment: By the way, they way you setup your ChannelInitializer every connected channel gets it's own ServerHandler. That way you can store things like a boolean in your ServerHandler that identifies the client of this ServerHandler is authenticated. The `channelRead0` method will only return in messages from that one client and not all.